# Inputting random numbers into an array

Tags: c, arrays, random

I tried to create an array and fill it with random numbers using rand(), and it would seem that I got the code to work but when I return the data to the screen it all appears to be correct except in value `arrayPrimary[5][2]`. It just shows a garbage value and I cant seem to figure out why it would do that in only this spot. I'm still new to learning the C language so please be as descriptive as possible to help me understand:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
srand (time(NULL));
int arrayPrimary[5][5];
int x,y,a,b;

for(x=1; x<6; x++)
{

    for (y=1; y<6; y++)
    {

    int *z= &arrayPrimary[x][y];
    *z=rand() %10;  

    }
}

for(a=1; a<6; a++)
{
    for(b=1; b<6;b++)
    {
    printf ("The current value of [%d][%d] is:%d\n",a,b,arrayPrimary[a][b]);
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Valid array indexes will be from `0 to 4` for both dimensions of `arrayPrimary` so you are invoking undefined behavior by accessing index `5`.

Comment: Where is `<stdio.h>` and `<time.h>` header?

Comment: I have both headers in my code I just forgot to copy them over.

Comment: Why are you bending yourself into a pretzel setting the values?  What's wrong with `arrayPrimary[x][y] = rand() % 10`?

Answer (score 2):

In C, array indexing starts from `0`.
Change

```
for(a=1; a<6; a++)
{
    for(b=1; b<6;b++)
```

to

```
for(a=0; a<5; a++)
{
     for(b=0; b<5;b++)
```